# How to display LWC Modal Popup when user login to salesforce org?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-modal

I have created a LWC modal popup which is currently displayed on home page once the home page gets loaded.

Requirement is

Display Modal Popup on the homepage when user freshly login to salesforce.

please provide a code for this.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can create a login flow.
Create a screen flow then use LWC inside that flow. And then you can use this screen flow in the login flow.
To create a login flow, follow these steps -

> 1. Go to Setup.
> 2. Search for Login Flow in Quick search.
> 3. Click on login flow.
> 4. Click on new.
> 5. Give a name to your login flow and choose the profile for which you want to enable it.
> 6. Save.

Comment: Login Flow displays message before it goes on home page, i need to display popup on home page at once when user loged in to salesforce.

Comment: I am not sure if we can do this or not. One thing that can be done is you can create a checkbox on the User record and on login, you can make that checkbox true and on the homepage, you can drop your LWC component and display the popup if the checkbox is true. And you need to uncheck that checkbox by scheduling or on modal close. But this will fail in edge cases.